# After setting PHP headers I'm receiving the meme type as the from value?

Tags: php, html, ajax, angularjs, email

This should be pretty straightforward. I'm sending an email using an Angular JS's HTTP object ajax request.

The ajax request works fine, my data is passed to the PHP in JSON format (The Angular JS default).

The email sends correctly, I'm just having issues with my header formatting. I have the following PHP code...

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $request = json_decode($postdata);

    $user_email = $request->email;
    $user_subject = $request->subject;
    $user_message_input = $request->message;

    $user_headers = 'From: ' . '<noReply@AllenHundley.com>' . '\r\n';
    $user_headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $user_headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

    $user_message = "
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>
                    Thanks for contacting me!
                </title>
            </head>
            <body>
                " . $user_message_input . "
            </body>
        </html>
    ";

    mail($user_email, $user_subject, $user_message, $user_headers);
```

As I mentioned before, the email sends as an HTML email. The only problem is that in my email I receive this as the from field:

`rnMIME-Version: 1.0 noReply@allenhundley.com`

Why are the separations being viewed as escaped strings rather than separators?

Comment: change `'\r\n';` to double quotes in your first header. Those don't get rendered properly in singles, but seen as a string literal.

Comment: I see it's been posted as an answer now.

Comment: My apologies @Fred-ii- i did not see your comment!  I did not mean to steal your answer

Comment: @mongjong No worries ;-) OP got their solution, *cheers*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\r\n` needs to be wrapped in double quotes, i.e. `"\r\n"`

In PHP, single quotes are for literal texts.  You can read more information here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: This was it. Thanks, I'll remember this in the future.